# Connecting class 2 power supplies in parallel

Tags: power-supply, power, parallel, certification, ul

I am looking to connect multiple rails in parallel to increase current of a class 2 power supply (UL1310). Each rail would have its own OCP (12V 8A). The problem I am having is that when talking to vendors some are not sure if this is allowed and others go with it. I can not find anywhere in the certification UL/IEC if this is allowed. I believe it is allowed for inherent limited power source but maybe not for a non inherent limited power source. I understand that load balancing will have to be designed in.
I am looking for a definitive answer, why would UL/IEC allow current multipliers on secondary circuits and still be labeled a Class 2 or LPS(seems like it just sidesteps all the safety), and if someone could point me to where it talks about this in certification. I know computer PCBs act this way.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should not parallel power supplies unless they are designed to be used in parallel.

The supplies will deliver slightly different voltages, so the higher-voltage supply will deliver most of the current, until it is pulled down to the same voltage as the lower-voltage supply - this may (probably will) mean that the higher-voltage supply will be overloaded before the lower-voltage supply starts supplying current.